# GHC `elem` optimization

Tags: optimization, ghc, static-analysis

Consider the following function from LYAH:

```
    removeNonUppercase st = [ c | c <- st, c `elem` ['A'..'Z']]
```

Will GHC optimize the `elem` test? E.g. by using a hash table. If the predicate list is large, such an optimization becomes necessary, and it would be annoying to have to do this manually, e.g. by constructing a `Data.set` or whatever it's called.

Comment: What is so annoying in adding the call `Set.fromList`?

Comment: I'd guess the proper optimisation would be to replace the lookup by a simple [`isUpper c`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:isUpper) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile it with GHC 8.0.2 using `-O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all`, you can see for yourself that there's no optimization done on the `elem` test:

```
lvl_r21d = eftChar 65# 90#

removeNonUppercase_go =
  \ ds_a1Vs ->
    case ds_a1Vs of _ {
      [] -> [];
      : y_a1Vx ys_a1Vy ->
        case elem $fEqChar y_a1Vx lvl_r21d of _ {
          False -> removeNonUppercase_go ys_a1Vy;
          True -> : y_a1Vx (removeNonUppercase_go ys_a1Vy)
        }
    }

removeNonUppercase = \ st_aqk -> removeNonUppercase_go st_aqk
```

Comment: At least it does constant folding instead of reconstructing the list every time :-)